# Last read line in file prints out as null

Tags: java, file-io, io

Im trying to read a whole text file with a method i created. All the lines of the text file does get printed out as i wanted but the very last line of the file when its printed appears as null when its printed out.

```
private void readFile(String Path) throws IOException{
    String text = ""; //String used in the process of reading a file

    //The file reader
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(
            new FileReader(Path));

    //Creating a new string builder.
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    while(text != null)
    {
        //Read the next line
        text = input.readLine();

        stringBuilder.append(text); //Adds line of text into the String Builder
        stringBuilder.append(newLine); //Adds a new line using the newLine string
    } 

    //Sets the text that was created with the stringBuilder
    SetText(stringBuilder.toString());
}
```

All the files gets printed out 100% as they should except the method adds an extra line at the bottom that says "null" How would i write code so this line wont appear at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop exit condition is in the wrong place.

```
while ((text = input.readLine()) != null) {
    stringBuilder.appendText(text)
    ...
```

Answer (score 4):

You can change this:

```
    while(text != null)
    {
        //Read the next line
        text = input.readLine();

        // ... do stuff with text, which might be null now
    }
```

to either this:

```
    while((text = input.readLine()) != null)
    {
        // ... do stuff with text
    }
```

or this:

```
    while(true)
    {
        //Read the next line
        text = input.readLine();
        if(text == null)
            break;

        // ... do stuff with text
    }
```

or this:

```
    text = input.readLine();
    while(text != null)
    {
        // ... do stuff with text

        //Read the next line
        text = input.readLine();
    }
```

as you prefer.

Comment: Or initialize text = input.readLine(); once before the loop, and again at the end of the loop body.

Comment: @jacobm: True . . . but does anyone actually prefer that?

Comment: I actually slightly prefer it, since it corresponds most directly to how I would explain what was going on in English. (Though it does require you to repeat the same line twice.)

Comment: @jacobm: Fair enough. Added. :-)

Comment: Which of theese ways are the way that will let my application run "Best" ?

Comment: @TheCompBoy: They're all equivalent. I prefer the `while(true)` approach, personally, because it lets me declare `text` inside the loop and mark it `final` -- I like to mark everything `final` that I can, since I think it makes code easier to reason about -- but other people feel differently. Really, whichever one makes you go, "Yes, this makes sense!", is the one you should go with.

Answer (score 0):

Using read ahead you'll get a cleaner solution, which is easily understood :

```
text = input.readLine();

while(text != null)
    {
        stringBuilder.append(text); //Adds line of text into the String Builder
        stringBuilder.append(newLine); //Adds a new line using the newLine string

        //Read the next line
        text = input.readLine();
    }
```

Using the principle of read ahead, you can almost always avoid bad exit conditions.